# Questions on the relations between action and partition in UML Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I am using UML and have some questions on the relationship between action and partition of activity diagram.Who can do me a favor to make them clear?

Q1: Can an action be put at the crossing of partitions?

Q2: If the answer for Q1 is yes, what's the relation between the action and those partitions?
Considering the inPartition role, I guess the action shouldn't belong to any partition.

Q3: The * at the ActivityPartition is disturbing me as well.
How can an action have relation with several partitions?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you specify what tool you're using? Answers to these questions, like many real-world UML questions, depend as much (or more) on how the tool works as on the UML standard.

Comment: I am trying Astah Professional and MagicDraw. It seems neither of them support crossing-partition-action.However, Do those tools obey UML spec sincerely? I concern on Spec much more.